# How to alternate values by multiIndex and preceding value in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, sequence, multi-index

I have the following similar multiIndex:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,1,1, 1], 
                 "B":[2,2,2,2,2], 
                 "C":[2,2,2,2,2], 
                 "D":[1,1,1,1,1]}).T 

df1=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
                 "B":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,], 
                 "C":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,], 
                 "D":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,]}).T

df= pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1) 

col0 = pd.Series(['Set 1','Set 1','Set 1','Set 1','Set 1','Set 2' ,'Set 2' ,'Set 2' ,'Set 2' ,'Set 2' ,'Set 2' ,'Set 2' ,'Set 2'])
col1 = df.columns
arrays = [col0, col1]
df.columns = arrays
```

With output:

```
  Set 1             Set 2                     
      0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A     1  1  1  1  1     1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
B     2  2  2  2  2     2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
C     2  2  2  2  2     1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
D     1  1  1  1  1     2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

I however want to transform this matrix in a matrix with the following desired output:

```
  Set 1             Set 2                     
      0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A     1  2  2  1  1     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
B     2  1  1  2  2     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
C     2  1  1  2  2     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
D     1  2  2  1  1     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
```

To explain:
I basically only want to keep the values of the first columns in each multiIndex 'Set #'. The values after the first columns should alternate based on the value in the first values. The values are to alternate between 1 and 2 each two columns.

Anything would help!

Comment: can you explain a bit more on the logic for the other columns barring the first in each mutiindex?

Comment: I want to have an indication matrix of who is on serve at that point. Player 1 or 2? The matrax I made resembles two tie-breaks in a tennis match. Herein the first point is served by the player that did not serve the previous game. After that the other player serves for two points. Then, the serve rotates every two points. @anky

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.  First, I started with your data (just transposed):

```
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd

# df created as per original post, then transposed (not shown to save space)

print(df.transpose())
  Set 1             Set 2                     
      0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A     1  1  1  1  1     1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
B     2  2  2  2  2     2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
C     2  2  2  2  2     1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
D     1  1  1  1  1     2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
```

Second, I created a function that gets the first score in a set, then has alternating pairs (e.g., 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...).  The function results a pandas Series.

```
def func(s):
    assert isinstance(s, pd.Series)
    assert s[0] in {1, 2}
    
    if s[0] == 1:  serves = [2, 2, 1, 1]
    else:          serves = [1, 1, 2, 2]
    
    indicators = [s[0]] + [
        c for _, c in zip(range(1, s.size), cycle(serves))
    ]
    return pd.Series(data=indicators, index=s.index, name=s.name)
```

Third, I grouped the data frame by the first level of the index (Set 1, Set 2, ...) and applied the function to each group.

```
grouped = df.groupby( df.index.get_level_values(0) )

for idx in grouped.groups.values():
    df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx].apply(lambda x: func(x))

print(df.transpose())

  Set 1             Set 2                     
      0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A     1  2  2  1  1     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
B     2  1  1  2  2     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
C     2  1  1  2  2     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
D     1  2  2  1  1     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the fact the columns you want to modify are of value 1 and 2 once modulo the second level of columns by 4. Then you can use `mask` twice to replace these columns and either where df is equal to 1 or 2.

```
mCol = np.isin(df.columns.get_level_values(1)%4, [1,2])
m1 = df.eq(1)
m2 = df.eq(2)
res_ = (df.mask(mCol&m1, 2)
          .mask(mCol&m2, 1))
print(res_)
  Set 1             Set 2                     
      0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A     1  2  2  1  1     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
B     2  1  1  2  2     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
C     2  1  1  2  2     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
D     1  2  2  1  1     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
```

This only work as expected if the value in the column 0 is the same than the rest of the line per Set of columns. Otherwise, you need to change m1 and m2 with this

```
m_ = df.where(df.eq(df)&(df.columns.get_level_values(1)==0)).ffill(1)
m1 = m_.eq(1)
m2 = m_.eq(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and dataset correctly, you want to flip values of columns where the 2nd level is in this mathematical sequence formular `4 * n + 1` and `4 * n + 2` where starting from `n = 0`. So, it is just a matter of constructing this sequence and use `query` to slice them to flip values and updating back.

Construct the sequence

```
import numpy as np

n = df.columns.max()[1]
m = (np.arange(n) * 4 + 1)
a = m.tolist() + (m + 1).tolist()
```

Flip all columns, `transpose` to use `query` with `ilevel_1` to select the specified columns to update. Finally, `transpose` back and `update`.

```
df.update((3 - df).T.query('ilevel_1 in @a').T)
print(df)
```

Or `transpose`, `query`, flipping values, `transpose` back and `update`

```
df.update((3 - df.T.query('ilevel_1 in @a')).T)  
print(df)

Out[357]:
  Set 1             Set 2
      0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A     1  2  2  1  1     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
B     2  1  1  2  2     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
C     2  1  1  2  2     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
D     1  2  2  1  1     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
```

---

If you don't want to `transpose` and `query` you may use `IndexSlice`, `loc`

```
ix = pd.IndexSice
df.update(3 - df.loc[:,ix[:, a]])

Out[399]:
  Set 1             Set 2
      0  1  2  3  4     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A     1  2  2  1  1     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
B     2  1  1  2  2     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
C     2  1  1  2  2     1  2  2  1  1  2  2  1
D     1  2  2  1  1     2  1  1  2  2  1  1  2
```